# create a div that would grow as if it is a bubble

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a circular background image inside a div. to start off with i need to not have the 'bubbles' to display. and after arriving on that page the bubble would grow into place like a bubble or in other words 'pop' into place. I have no idea how i would go about creating this in jquery. this also needs to work on all browsers including ie7+ any help would be grateful

Comment: i havent been able to try anything as i havent even got a clue where to start. im not a begginer at jquery but woudlnmt know what to start to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the popping effect you really need to animate 4 different styles, depending on your CSS preference you can animate top and left or if you're using margins (why?) margin-top and margin-left, this will give you the effect of the "bubble" expanding center outwards instead of top left to bottom right.

**This is a jQuery example for top/left**

```
var newHeight = 300;
var newWidth = 300;

jQuery('#element').animate({
    "top":newHeight/2,
    "left":newWidth/2,
    "height":newHeight,
    "width":newWidth,
    "opacity":1
}, 'fast', easeInOutCirc);
```

You may find the easing effects here: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

its worth noting you should be a little more specific with your questions, we're not mind readers :)

Comment: thanks for the replys guys. on this website [here][1] there is a bubble effect but it is only growing from left to right. i would like something to grow from center outwards i wish i coudl find a example to show but i have nothing to show and cant show any example as i have nothing. all i have is a div with a circle bg image
  [1]: http://1minus1.com/develop

Comment: That's exactly what the above example should do, your element should be absolutely positioned and you should be ready to rock and roll!

Comment: ah okay. cool thanks for the help. ill give this a try tomorrow in the morning. and let you know

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery show() function](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

[jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

These should give you an idea.
You might also consider using images to illustrate what you're trying to achieve.

I recommend building the content you need, and then asking people how you can change it to get the results you want. That will be easier for people to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtanders/uzkdz/) where I did something very similar to what you're doing.  Hope it helps.

```
function(){
    var position = $('#bubbleposition'),
        bubble = $('#bubble'),
        startRadius = 200,
        newRadius = 400,
        startleft = 10,
        starttop = 10,
        endleft = 50,
        endtop = 50;
    position.css({left: startleft, top: starttop, 10)});
    bubble.css({height: startRadius, width: startRadius});
    position.animate({left: endleft, top: endtop});
    bubble.animate({height: newRadius, width: newRadius}, 400);
}

<div id='bubbleposition'>
    <div id='bubble'>
        Hello!
    </div>
</div>
```